# Blazor WASM Site Doesn't Work In Firefox When Served Via Apache

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM site that I have created to replace an existing website that I have taken over hosting for. Until the current term is up, I am hosting the site on GoDaddy, which uses Apache.

The site is working great, except for that Blaozr fails to initialize in Firefox when it is being hosted from GoDaddy. Every other browser I have tried works fine without any issues, and Firefox works fine if I use something like `dotnet serve` to test locally.

The error I get is

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError whe attempting to fetch resource.

The stacktrace is in the image below

[image]

After finding [this documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#apache-1), I tried making some changes to the `.htaccess` file on the server. It currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?redacted\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.redacted.com/$1 [R,L]

AddType application/wasm wasm
AddType application/octet-stream dll
AddType application/wasm .wasm
AddType application/octet-stream .dll

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/octet-stream
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
        <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
            BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
            BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
            BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I also tried creating a brand-new Blazor WASM project, publishing it, and hosting that. It has the same issue.

I am at a loss for how to troubleshoot this issue further. Does anyone know what may be wrong?